# Is it possible to enjoy online app in offline mode in this problem?

Tags: applications, apk, offline

This is **not** about changing the online app into offline by Lucky Patcher so that I don't bother with ads. No, it's not.

The app is a dictionary which requires the internet to open each entry. Actually the app offers the download button, but only for each entry which I should download all of those entries so that I can enjoy it offline if I want. But I don't think that's a clever method because there are millions of words!

Is it possible to batch download i.e. all activities are done in one action instantly by probably modifying the app? (*Don't worry about the topic of hacking, it's not hacking at all since the app is totally free and there's no premium feature either*).

I have searched the related problem, I don't remember where, the difference is the website I visited, discussing the possibility to download the data from *wiktionary* so that one can enjoy the dictionary offline. So, I'm asking this question, hoping that it's a possible thing and I can do the same thing to the app.

Comment: You should just ask the app developer for the feature. If you are thinking about a dictionary like Wiktionary, see: [Download all words from Wiktionary for offline use](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18273/2543) Do realize that Wiktionary EN is about 20 GB compressed. The biggest problem is what you want to batch download may be different than someone else and that will require app developer to make changes.

Comment: @MorrisonChang alas they don't answer my email when I ask this problem

Comment: Regardless of whether it's hacking or not, this community generally doesn't have experience in reverse-engineering/modding an app since it's a borderline issue related to app development, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @user516076 You may want to look through relevant [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+dictionary) to see if anything matches. If you want to post a request there, I would make sure you describe exactly what words you are trying to 'batch': i.e. middle school vocabulary, TOEFL, certain science terms, etc. and do search for dictionary apps with required terms in the Play Store. If the UI experience is problematic describe it and how to change it could fit your needs.